# Autocomplete using advanced model in wicket

Tags: ajax, model, wicket

First I want to say I saw a site:
https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/autocomplete-using-a-wicket-model.html

Still I have some problem with implementation.

**Context**
I have form where want to edit Order from my database. 
I want to autocomplete client's name in form and save it to database.

**Problem**
I can see suggestions of client names and I can choose which client's name I'll use.
Just when I submit form new client won't be saved in order, in database.
I don't know how to relate form Model with AutoCompleteTextField input.

Any ideas ?

Pseudo code of my classes:

```
Order{
  Long id;
  String date;
  Client client;
  Status status;
  ...
}

Client{
  Long id;
  String name;
  String nip;
  String address;
  String postcode;
  String city;
  String phone;
  String mail;
  ...
}

Status{
   Long id;
   String name;
   String value;
}
```

**Edited:**
Yes you are right.

My implementation of AbstractAutoCompleteTextField from site:

```
AbstractAutoCompleteRenderer autoCompleteRenderer = new AbstractAutoCompleteRenderer() {

                protected final String getTextValue(final Object object) {
                    Client client = (Client) object;
                    return client.getName();
                }

                protected final void renderChoice(final Object object, final Response response, final String criteria) {
                    response.write(getTextValue(object));
                }

            };


            // textfield
            AbstractAutoCompleteTextField<Client> name = new AbstractAutoCompleteTextField<Client>("name", new PropertyModel(order, "client"), autoCompleteRenderer) {

                protected final List<Client> getChoiceList(final String input) {
                    return clientService.findByNames(10, 0, input);
                }

                protected final String getChoiceValue(final Client choice) throws Throwable {
                    return choice.getId().toString();
                }
            };
form.add(name);
```

My form implementation you asked for:

```
form = new Form("orderForm", new CompoundPropertyModel(order)) {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                orderService.update((Order) getDefaultModelObject());
                setResponsePage(OrdersPage.class);
                // Form validation successful. Display message showing edited
                // model.
            }
        };
```

With this code I got: "'Hurtownia Techniczna "ADA"' is not proper Client." (translated from Polish) in feedback panel.

Comment: So if I get this right, your autocomplete is working, but the value selected on the form is not stored when the form is submitted? If so we'd probably need to see some code of how you handle form submission..

Comment: within `orderService.update()` do you update the client too?

Comment: I guess I should. When I use DropDownChoice to edit status it's enough. I added Status class in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, that's where things go wrong:
`AbstractAutoCompleteTextField<Client> name = new AbstractAutoCompleteTextField<Client>("name", new PropertyModel(order, "client"), autoCompleteRenderer)`

**Rest of the answer edited to reflect the correct use case**

To be specific: You're creating a PropertyModel of your orders client value, which is a Client-Object and tie it to a TextField. To create a Client-object from the TextField, wicket needs a converter. There are lots of build-in converters but none of them is capable of converting to a custom object. Thus you'll need to provide the converter by implementing IConverter. Since I don't know how you store and retrieve your Client-objects I can only show you a generic example, a Locale-Converter used in one of my projects:

```
public class LocaleConverter implements IConverter {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3251433094703013493L;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.wicket.util.convert.IConverter#convertToObject(java.lang.String, java.util.Locale)
     */
    @Override
    public Object convertToObject(String value, Locale locale) {
    Locale retValue = null;
    try {
        retValue = LocaleUtils.toLocale(value);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw (new ConversionException("" + value + " is not a valid locale.", e));
    }
    return retValue;
}

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.wicket.util.convert.IConverter#convertToString(java.lang.Object, java.util.Locale)
     */
    @Override
    public String convertToString(Object value, Locale locale) {
        return value.toString();
    }

}
```

Then you'll need to register your new converter to your application. Again, this will be slightly different for you since you've got a different converter...

```
@Override
protected IConverterLocator newConverterLocator() {
    ConverterLocator newConverterLocator = (ConverterLocator) super.newConverterLocator();
    newConverterLocator.set(Locale.class, new LocaleConverter());
    return newConverterLocator;
}
```

This method needs to be included in your application class.

Comment: I tried this way: PropertyModel(order.getClient(), "name"). This way I can submit form but client won't update (there is still old one).

Comment: Do you think I can use IConverter to make 2 textfields (name and nip) autocopletable or it's possible with just one textfield?

Comment: a) You'll still have to update your Client in your orderService. Status works because you're setting a new object (changing the foreign key inside the order-table.
b)I don't think the IConverter will help here. This just isn't the right use-case. I just added this part as an excursus.

Comment: a) In 1h I'll try do function orderService.update(Order order, Client client) but I don't like this solution I'll have to do it for Device object and others also. I'll tell you how it will get on b) I know :/

Comment: If you change a value in your client object, this change needs to be written to your database, that's how things work. Most ORM-Frameworks offer ways to cascade persists, I only know Hibernate which allows it by the way of an annotation. Sure, you can create a new Client-object and automatically persist this one when persisting your order but then you'll have to delete the old Client-object or face a seriously polluted database.

Comment: Ok. I use hibernate + spring + wicket. In OrderService I use orderDAO.merge(order);. orderDAO extends DAO<Order, Long>. Now I'll try to implement that orderService.update(Order order, Client client)

Comment: First of, you don't need that second parameter. The client object is already there (`order.getClient()`). Second with hibernate and Annotations, you could just slap `@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)` on your `getClient()` method in Order. Not sure about the syntax with hbm, never bothered to use xml-configs for hibernate.

Comment: Will cascade change client's name or change client in order? When at autocomplete textfield I choose another client I want to change client's id in that order in database. (Your syntax is ok)

Comment: It will change client's name. Is it possible to change client in order not client's name ?

Comment: If you really want to change the whole client (sorry, I discarded this option), you'll indeed need an `IConverter`. To me an order belonged to a client and this couldn't be what you'd want to change, but it seems like it is... So you'll need an IConverter to load the selected client from the database or from cache...